# how to check a deeply nested object is undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I would like to check whether an object is undefined

this.state.data.value[0].name

I attempted the following
and these will say Type error this.state.data.value is undefined in the console.

```
if(typeof this.data.value[0].name=== "undefined"){
//do something
}

if(this.data.value[0].name == undefined){
//do something
}

if(!!this.data.value[0].name){
//do something
}

if(!this.data.value[0].name){
//do something
}

if(this.data){
  if(this.data.value){ // It says type error, this.state.value is undefined in the console.
    }
}
```

How shall I check the object this.state.value[0].name is undefined?

I attempted this

```
 if (typeof (this.data) !== undefined) {
      debugger;
      if (typeof (this.data.value) !== undefined) {
        debugger;

        if (typeof (this.data.value[0].name != undefined)) {//cannot read value [0]
          debugger;


        }
      }
    }
```

**My Solution**, thanks to [pranav-c-balan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3037257/pranav-c-balan)

```
  if (this.data && this.data.value && this.data.value[0] && this.data.value[0].name) {
      return true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("myDIV").innerHTML =
        "<b>Custom Error Text</b>";
      return false;

    }
```

A working Example

```js
   let data={};
    data.value=[{name:123}];

    function checkValue(){
      if(data && data.value && data.value[0] && data.value[0].name){
        return true;
      }else{
         return false;
      }
     }
     let correct=checkValue();
     
       if(correct){
          console.log("This is valid, data.value[0].name Exist");
          }else{
          console.log("This is invalid,data.value[0].name do not Exist");

          }

  function checkValue2(){
      if(data && data.value && data.value[0] && data.value[0].names){
        return true;
      }else{
         return false;
      }
     }

let correct2=checkValue2();
 if(correct2){
          console.log("This is valid, data.value[0].names Exist");
          }else{
          console.log("This is invalid,data.value[0].names do not Exist");

          }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `this.state.data.value &&`

Comment: @VLAZ, no because the example you shown it one layer of object, but I would like to check a nested object this .state.value[0].name
it could be chances this.state.value exist but do not have .name property then I want this if statement to catch it and do something.

neverthless, when I write this.state.value the console already throws an error saying this.state.value is undefined

Comment: @PranavCBalan I tried   if (!this.data && !this.data.value && !this.data.value[0] && !this.data.value[0].name) {
// the if statement was not evaluated

Comment: @RandomI.T `!this.data` means that it will only go in if it's *falsy*, so if `this.data` exists, it will be skipped. Remove the NOT.

Comment: @PranavCBalan, I like your idea, Its Simple and it works!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can check your object by using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (`?.`).

This will check every part of your chain. Say if it is undefined the `data` inside the `state` then it returns `undefined` excepts throwing an error.

```js
let state = {
  data: {
    value: [
      {name: 'value'}
    ]
  }
}

console.log(typeof state?.data?.value?.[0]?.name);
console.log(typeof state?.data?.value?.[1]?.name);
console.log(typeof state?.datum?.value?.[0]?.name); // In this case it returns 'undefined' for dutum stage.
```

## Note

Optional chaining has poor browser support until now. So you have to use `Babel` or any other Javascript compiler for browser support.

Comment: The standard is NOT finalised. Support is not widely available, either. You need to use Babel for this. TypeScript also allows it.

Comment: Yes, you have to use Babel for support. But as you are using React I hope the babel is configured well. :)

Comment: People who don't use React are also able to see this post. In fact, OP is in the extreme minority of people who would see this post - that would be a single view, everybody else who reads the post is *not* OP and might or might not have React or Babel available. Remember, posts are not for individuals - they are for everybody.

Comment: I get your point @VLAZ. Thanks for your suggestion. I am mentioning this in my answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply it says syntax error I cannot compile using gulp bundle

Comment: You can use this ```gulp-babel``` plugin for your Gulp. https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same **typeof** operator:

```
if(typeof(this.state) != 'undefined'){
  if(typeof(this.state.value) != 'undefined') { 
        // next source
    }
}
```

Comment: `typeof` is not a function, it's an operator.

Comment: I attempted this and it says this.data.value is undefined